# Symfony/doctrine consuming to much memory, out of memory error

Tags: php, apache, symfony, doctrine

I want to get data from a table and encode it in json. I'm using doctrine and the querybuilder to select the data I want (which is everything from the table basically). The problem is that in dev, everything work fine, but when I go to prod I get the error : PHP Fatal error : Out of memory ...

The data i'm retrieving is 300KB at most. 
In this case I'm using a route to retrieve a list of *project* (600B) , it's one of the smallest table.
This table has two *OneToMany* associations.

[image: The database looks like this]

The data i'm retrieving looks like this :

```
[
  {
   id: "bar",
   name: "bar",
   description: "bar",
   project_date_start: "2022-01-01 00:00:00",
   project_date_end: "2019-05-21 12:19:27"
  },
  {
   id: "foo",
   name: "foo",
   description: "foo",
   project_date_start: "2021-02-02 00:00:00",
   project_date_end: "2022-02-02 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

The doctrine's querybuilder and the function :

```
    public function findAllProject()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p.id', 'p.name', 'p.description', 'p.project_date_start', 'p.project_date_end')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

```
        public function project(Request $request)
        { 
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

            $projectRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Project::class);

            $project = $projectRepo->findAllProject();

            $data = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($project, 'json');

            $response = new Response($data);
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

            return $response;
        }
```

I've tried :
- reinstalling Apache on the server
- changing the value of the memory_limit in the php.ini
- not using *jms_serialiser* and using *json_encode* instead

**EDIT**

So the error is definitly not comming from the serializer, since the error is thrown while i'm getting the data from the repository (*findAllProject()*).

I've managed to make it work by reducing the data i'm retrieving, but it's not a solution since I need all the data and as I said *project* is one of the smallest table, so what about when I need the retrieve bigger data ?

If i'm getting data back from symfony, maybe it's not symfony but apache, what could cause this error ?

Also, the generated SQL comming from the queryBuilder is good (juste a normal select)

**END EDIT**

I don't think it's a problem with the json encoding part nor an apache server configuration problem (the memory limit is at -1).

I think the association of the *project* table is messing up everything and doctrine is trying to go throught all the database. Maybe a problem with the design of my database ?
For exemple, the table *type* is the same size as *project* but don't have the out of memory error.

I don't know what else I can try, any idea ?

Comment: Looks like you are just dealing with a single entity and not any of its associations so start by removing `select` and use `getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY/HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT)` . More importantly you are running serializer on everything (all projects) you are fetching from DB which is more like a "disaster waiting to happen" type of practise - don't do that!

Comment: I tried using `getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY/HYDRATE_SIMPLEOBJECT)` but coudn't make it work, have you a link that explain how to use it ? I'm fearly new to symfony/doctrine. What is the best way to handle serialization then ? Cause the 'project' array is rly small and the object in itself is rly simple, I don't see how this could be a problem for jms_serialiser. Thank you

Comment: just out of curiosity: have you tried setting the env on your dev machine to "prod" and if that works, checking https://php.net/memory_get_usage to see how much memory is being used. I mean, maybe your server actually has too little memory. if it's not actually such a big amount of memory: I read once from another person, that had a one-bit-flip in the php executable and it caused out-of-memory whenever he serialized stuff. sooo ... you could try to reinstall php ...

Comment: *if* the out of memory appears on the serializer-line: try (for testing purposes) other serializations like just calling json_encode, print_r, var_dump, var_export, ...

Comment: I've tested the prod config on my local machine and it works fine. As I said in my post i've already tried différent way of serialization, I rly don't think it's a serialization problem cause i'm getting the error when my data is fetch.

Answer (score 0):

So, I reinstalled my server from scratch then my project and it worked, so I don't know what was causing this issue.